# z-index issue in Chrome/Safari and Firefox (nesting elements)

Tags: html, css, ipad, browser, z-index

Basically `.second` has to be above `.third`. Which only is in Firefox though. Unfortunatelly I can't move `.second` out of `.fifth`, which is why it is giving me such a hard time.

For further information: `.third` is supposed to be a modal background to darken the content `.fifth` and the footer `.fourth`. The modals content is `.second`. The Web-App is supposed to be for Safari on iPad.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgpjrd4r/1/)**

```
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="fifth">
    <div class="second">I should be on top.</div>
</div>
<div class="third"></div>
<div class="fourth"></div>
```

```
.first{
    z-index: 10;
    /* styling */
    position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; height: 50px; background: lightblue;
}
.second{
    z-index: 9;
    /* styling */
    position: fixed; top: 100px; left: 50px; right: 50px; bottom: 100px; background: darkseagreen;
}
.third{
    z-index: 8;
    /* styling */
    position: fixed; top: 50px; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.fourth{
    z-index: 7;
    /* styling */
    position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; height: 50px; background: indianred;
}
.fifth{
    /* styling */
    position: fixed; top: 50px; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 50px; background: darkgrey;
}
```

Comment: Solved. Managed to move `.second` out of `.fifth`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to move `.second` out of `.fifth` in the end. Works for me, unfortunately no satisfying answer.

Answer (score 1):

Give `.fifth` a `z-index` greater than `.third`.

```css
    .first{
        z-index: 10;
        /* styling */
        position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; height: 50px; background: lightblue;
    }
    .second{
        z-index: 9; /* You probably do not need this */
        /* styling */
        position: fixed; top: 100px; left: 50px; right: 50px; bottom: 100px; background: darkseagreen;
    }
    .third{
        z-index: 8;
        /* styling */
        position: fixed; top: 50px; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    .fourth{
        z-index: 7;
        /* styling */
        position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; height: 50px; background: indianred;
    }
    .fifth{
        z-index: 9;
        /* styling */
        position: fixed; top: 50px; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 50px; background: darkgrey;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="fifth">
        <div class="second">I should be on top.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="third"></div>
    <div class="fourth"></div>
```

Comment: That pushes the overlay `.third` is behind `.fifth`, which doesn't work

Comment: Is `.third` used only for background coloring? Does it contain any content?

Comment: Only for coloring, It's generated by Bootstaps modal plugin. But I managed to move the modal further out. Now it is displaying correctly. Sorry for not answering, I wasn't able to use my pc at work due holidays :)